# Quando escrever números por extenso?

Tags: ortografia, português-europeu, números

Talvez a primeira destas duas perguntas se aplique tanto a português como a outras línguas.

Estou particularmente interessado em português de Portugal, mas uma resposta ideal tratará várias versões da língua.

> Quando escrever números por extenso e quando escrever com algarismos?

Uma regra que uso, para bem ou para mal, é a seguinte. Por exemplo, escreveria "Duas bolas" em vez de "2 bolas" por quando leio o algarismo 2, não sei se é "dois" ou "duas". Atendendo a que os números um e dois são os únicos que têm esta particularidade, se houver mais que duas unidades do objeto, raciocino com duas unidades e adapto ao número de objetos em questão. Esta forma de pensar está errada?

Comment: Peço a quem esteja por dentro das tags que adicione as que considerar indicadas.

Comment: Essa é complicada...

Comment: A segunda parte, embora pretenda justificar uma linha de pensamento da primeira, aborda um assunto bem diferente. Apenas acontece que o "um" e o "dois" têm formas diferentes no masculino e no feminino.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uma regra clara para isso é o caso do "um" e do "uma". Quando são empregados como artigos, devem ser escritos por extenso. Quando expressão numerais, podem ou não ser escritos por extenso.

Por exemplo:

> Um menino bateu à porta.
>   1 menino bateu à porta.

Neste caso, a primeira forma sempre está correta (a palavra "um" está empregada como um artigo indefinido). A segunda forma depende do contexto da frase, e só estará correta se a finalidade do 1 for a de expressar quantidade, e não que simplesmente "alguém bateu à porta".

Nas demais situações, tanto faz se o numeral é escrito por extenso ou não. Entretanto, por vezes é mais conveniente escrevê-lo em formato numérico. Por exemplo:

> A raiz quadrada de 81 é 9.
>   A raiz quadrada de oitenta e um é nove.

> A área total do município é de 8746578 m².
>   A área total do município é de oito milhões, setecentos e quarenta e seis mil, quinhentos e setenta e oito metros quadrados.

> O pagamento de R$ 15,22 foi efetuado.
>   O pagamento de quinze reais e vinte e dois centavos foi efetuado.

Além disso, o "um" e o "dois" **não** são os únicos numerais que podem variar com o género, existem mais oito numerais não-compostos nesta categoria, a saber:

> duzent**o**s - duzent**a**s
>   trezent**o**s - trezent**a**s
>   quatrocent**o**s - quatrocent**a**s
>   quinhent**o**s - quinhent**a**s
>   seiscent**o**s - seiscent**a**s
>   setecent**o**s - setecent**a**s
>   oitocent**o**s - oitocent**a**s
>   novecent**o**s - novecent**a**s

Comment: Tangencialmente relacionado: pode começar-se uma frase com um algarismo?

Comment: @GitGud Sim, claro: "257 novas casas foram construídas no bairro".

Comment: O primeiro caso é um pouco falacioso, atenda à minha resposta.

Comment: Acrescento também que a pergunta está apontada para o português de Portugal.

Comment: @E_net4 Quanto ao primeiro questionamento, eu digo que é por isso que na resposta eu escrevi "*Quando são empregados como artigos, devem ser escritos por extenso.*", mas para evitar mal-entendidos, eu coloquei um parênteses depois para reforçar isso. Quanto ao segundo, sim a pergunta está para o português europeu, mas não vejo nada na resposta que necessite de algo específico para o português europeu, apenas troquei "gênero" por "género". Se houver algo a mais, me aponte.

Comment: Sim, agora está bem.

Answer (score 8):

Em jornalismo, e em ensaios, a regra é escrever por extenso os números de zero a dez, e como algarismo todos os outros.

Usei aqui a [respectiva secção do *The Economist Style Guide*](http://www.economist.com/style-guide/figures), um dos *standards* para a língua inglesa (agradeço a quem possa fornecer equivalente referência para a língua portuguesa):

> 1. Evite começar uma frase com um algarismo. Escreva sempre por extenso.
> 2. Escreva por extenso os números de um a dez, excepto em:
>
>    - referências a páginas
>    - percentagens
>    - unidades de medida
>    - descrições de cálculos
>    - conjuntos de números em que pelo menos um seja maior do que dez.
> 3. É permissível usar números por extenso em quantidades redondas, ou aproximações.

**Exemplos**

*Foram enviadas para o local quatro das sete viaturas.*
*Foram enviadas para o local 9 das 43 viaturas.*
*Passados 60 dias, não houve ainda resposta à petição pública.*
*Cerca de **duas centenas** de protestantes reuniram-se à porta da assembleia.*
*Foram anunciadas **quinhentas** novas vagas.*

Comment: Eu preferiria `Evite começar uma frase com um algarismo.` Se a frase começar com um número de vários dígitos, fica estranho por extenso.

Comment: @ANeves Na fonte que referi, usam o termo "never", mas claro que, não sendo um documento oficial da língua, mas uma convenção profissional, a mesma prescrição não se aplica aqui. Editei seguindo a sua sugestão.

Comment: Língua portuguesa, você pode usar o manual de redação da folha de Sao Paulo. http://www.acmcomunicacao.com.br/wp-content/midias/Manual-de-Redacao-Folha-de-SP.pdf (versão compilada por outra pessoa)

Answer (score 6):

A língua portuguesa não estabelece estritamente uma regra para quando escrever por extenso ou por algarismos. Tanto posso ter "555 pães" como "quinhentos e cinquenta e cinco pães". O que poderá surgir na escrita de documentos mais formais é uma convenção ou norma que deve ser cumprida de acordo com o contexto, normalmente para facilitar a leitura. Uma possível seria usar a forma em extenso se e só se o número for um numeral não composto (ex: *seis*, *dois*, *quinhentos*, *33*, *2014*). Este tipo de normas não fazem parte da gramática.

Acrescento contudo, o caso à parte em que um número representa um século: devemos escrevê-lo em numeração romana (ex: "século XIII" em vez de "século 13").

Também adiciono o que disse nos comentários: Os números "um" e "dois" são os únicos numerais dentro das unidades (porque nas centenas também surgem outros casos) que têm formas diferentes no masculino e no feminino, mas este facto não impõe nenhuma regra na escrita destes números.

---

O caso mencionado pelo @VictorStafusa relativamente à palavra "um" está bem apontado, mas aí a palavra não é um numeral, mas sim o artigo indefinido do singular. "1 menino está à porta" ou "1 dia vou para Guimarães" são frases incorretas, mas apenas surgem como uma má interpretação da diferença entre o numeral e o artigo indefinido.

Comment: `*disseste :-P`

Comment: Não. Fui eu que disse.

Comment: Ahhh! Percebi mal.

Comment: @ANeves De todos os modos, a distinção entre os numerais e os artigos indefinidos foi uma constatação à parte.