# Pode-se começar frases por algarismos?

Tags: números

Pode-se começar frases por algarismos ou tem de se escrever o número por extenso?

Recentemente numa [outra pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/407/quando-escrever-n%C3%BAmeros-por-extenso) foi-me dito tanto que sim, como que não. Peço então que as respostas sejam apoiadas por fontes.

Comment: Não houve discordância entre as respostas dessa pergunta, houve apenas um caso particular em que "um" era o artigo indefinido, que não pode ser substituído por "1" porque simplesmente não é um numeral.

Comment: @E_net4 Nota [este](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/407/quando-escrever-n%C3%BAmeros-por-extenso#comment683_410) comentário e [esta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/693/113) resposta. É a isto que me refiro.

Comment: isso relaciona-se com uma norma proposta por uma entidade para a redação de documentos, não faz parte da gramática. Só imagino respostas aqui a reforçarem esta ideia.

Comment: @E_net4 Sim, reparei nisso, mas a contradição existe à mesma. Procuro saber, afinal de contas, o que está correto.

Comment: Nestes casos não sei onde é que acaba a gramática normativa (quem é que decide estas coisas?) e começa a estética, ou até onde é que as duas se entrelaçam. Eu evito ao máximo começar uma frase com algarismos, simplesmente porque não gosto. Chego a reordenar a frase para mandar o número lá para o meio, se não me parecer natural escrevê-lo por extenso.

Answer (score 3):

Sim. No entanto, a prática é escrever os números por extenso.

> Trinta pessoas compareceram hoje.

Há um cuidado especial quanto a percentuais. Por exemplo, é correto começar a frase por numeral e símbolo.

> 25% dos alunos passaram na matéria.

E por extenso também:

> Vinte e cinco por cento dos alunos passaram na matéria.

Mas é errado misturar numeral e forma extensa, e vice-versa:

> 25 por cento dos alunos passaram na matéria. (errado)

[Uma fonte está aqui](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/frase-iniciada-por-um-algarismo/28576).